# Drawing a curve over a curved surface

Tags: opengl, glsl, hlsl

When drawing a line over a mesh, OpenGL allows to use glPolygonOffset to make sure the line is draw over the faces of the mesh.

Now when drawing a (say NURBS) surface, the parameter space of the surface is sampled to create a mesh representing the surface. Now if I want to draw an isoline, over the surface, the isoline is sampled at a fixed parameter u or v. Now it turns out that the lines of the isoline does not go through the exact triangles of the surface mesh (because of the sampling described above). Hence glPolygonOffset will not work in this case.

Then what is the right way to draw an line on a curved surface?

Comment: i'm familiar with the problem. not so much with any solution. disabling depth is sometimes a solution depending on the viewpoint and surface shape. a bigger glPolygonOffset can work if mesh and line geometry is dense enough. projecting the line as a sort of light source onto the mesh might also work though controling line width becomes a little tricky.

Comment: You may also use the stencil buffer, drawing the lines first.

Comment: The stencil buffer will prevent the parts of the line that should really be hidden by the surface (because a part of the surface is really in front of another part of the line) to actually be hidden, or am I getting things wrong?

Comment: I do this sometimes by texturing the surface and render the 2D stuff directly into the texture. Of coarse the texture resolution is limited and Intel gfx cards has problems with FBO and direct texture rendering (can be done by `glReadPixels + glTexImage` instead but that is slow and not suitable in some cases). Another option is to render your 2D stuff in Fragment shader analytically but that is not doable for too complex 2D meshes and also requires passing your geometry as a texture ...